# Extending Android media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to extend the built in media player, however when i grab the sources, there are a lot of external dependencies that are hard to track down.

Is there any way to get the source and the dependencies so that i can have it as a standalone and then extend it, is this even possible?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the built-in applications, such as the media player, are designed to be built as part of the firmware. Trying to just take the sources and use them with the SDK probably will not work, at least not in its present form.

AFAIK, your choices are to either use the firmware build process (best if you are trying to contribute patches back to Android), work to make the media player buildable on the SDK (contributing patches back) and then extending it, starting from scratch, or starting from an existing open source Android media player and contributing there (if there is one).